# Iterator stores the wrong value after splicing list

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, iterator

I have some simple code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

std::list<int> A;
std::list<int> B;
std::list<int>::iterator location;

int main()
{
    A.push_back( 1 );
    location = A.begin();
    B.splice( B.end(), A, A.begin() );
    std::cout<< (*location) <<std::endl;
}
```

After compilation I get the runtime error: List iterator not dereferenceable. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: to store the pointer to this element?

Comment: Your library and compiler must be ancient. `void main` is invalid. `<conio.h>` is ancient. [Code works in GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ffe2a1dfed9c7bb).

Comment: msvc 2008, i know))) this is sketch

Comment: compiler give me error, that list iterator not dereferencable

Comment: @juanchopanza: `std::list<>::splice` does not invalidate iterators, though it may invalidate ranges.

Comment: you mean that this code must to work?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Looking at the C++03 standard re. that overload, "*Inserts an element pointed to by i from list x before position and removes the element from x. The result is unchanged if position == i or position == ++i. Invalidates only the iterators and references to the spliced element.*".

Comment: @juanchopanza: So that changed in C++11? Didn't know that.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It seems so, I didn't know either. Complexity stays the same, so I'm not sure what gives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overload of `std::splice::list` that you are using invalidates iterators to the spliced element in C++03. From **23.2.2.4 list operations** **[lib.list.ops]**:

> `void splice(iterator position, list<T,Allocator>& x, iterator i);`
>
> **Effects**: Inserts an element pointed to by i from list x before position and removes the element from x. The result is unchanged if
>   position == i or position == ++i. *Invalidates only the iterators and
>   references to the spliced element*.

(emphasis mine)

So in your case, `location`, which you initialized with `A.begin()` before splicing it, becomes invalidated. This behaviour appears to have changed in C++11, where iterator validity is maintained (see [**working example**](http://ideone.com/RJkred).)